# Why is my Private Gallery not accessible from Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-extensions

I have created a Visual Studio extension and have tried to publish it on my company's internal SharePoint server.

I have followed the instructions on https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/extensibility/private-galleries?view=vs-2019

and registered the gallery via the *Tools | Options | Extensions and Updates* dialog and provided a link to the relevant page on our server.

When I try access the gallery from the Extensions and Updates dialog I just get the error:

[image: error message]

Does anyone know what I need to do to get this to work?

Comment: It looks like you need to give Visual Studio an Atom feed URL, but you've given it an HTML page - a SharePoint list page? I don't know SharePoint well enough to tell you how to get an Atom feed from that.

Comment: The documentation says that you can use an atom feed or a sharepoint site.  I have tried adding the feed.xml file into the sharepoint folder but that does not seem to help

Comment: Fair enough - it just says Atom at the top of the page you linked too, and the error message is consistent with it expecting Atom. I'd check then that it has registered your URL as a SharePoint site, e.g. the pkgdef fragment has a Protocol= property: find the registry key that it has created for your gallery (e.g. search by URL) and make sure it has Protocol=Sharepoint set too.

Comment: My pkgdef does not contain a protocal entry?  I thought that the pkgdef setup happened when the project was built?  Is there something else I need to do with it?

Comment: I'm looking at [this page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/extensibility/how-to-manage-a-private-gallery-by-using-registry-settings?view=vs-2019). It has the gallery URL in it, so I assume it can't be generated automatically? There is a Protocol entry in there.

Comment: That's probably just a gallery definition pkgdef then, not the extension pkgdef. Sorry, I don't know much about these. However I am fairly confident your problem is that VS expecting your URL to be an Atom feed not SharePoint, though, so you'll need to work out how to configure that.